# Find the area of the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = a^2$ that is outside the cylinders $x^2 + y^2 − ax = 0$ and $x^2 + y^2 + ax = 0$.

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm completely stuck with this problem. I know I have to convert it into polar coordinates but that's about all that I have figured out.

Answer (score 0):

The area of the surface $z= f(x,y),\: (x,y)\in D$ is given by the double integral
\begin{equation*}
A=\iint_{D}\sqrt{1+\left(f'_{x}\right)^{2}+\left(f'_{y}\right)^{2}}\, dxdy.
\end{equation*}
We calculate the area inside the cylinders.

At first we study the surface $z=\sqrt{a^2-x^2-y^2},\:  (x,y)\in D,$ where $D$ is the half-disc defined by $x^2+y^2-ax\le 0,\: x \ge 0.$ Its area $A$ is given by\begin{equation*}
A= \iint_{D}\sqrt{1+\left(\dfrac{-x}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2-y^2}}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{-y}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2-y^2}}\right)^2}\, dxdy = \iint_{D}\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2-y^2}}\, dxdy.
\end{equation*}
If $x = r\cos t, y=r\sin t$ and $(x,y)\in D$ then $0\le t \le \frac{\pi}{2},\: 0 \le r \le a\cos t$. Consequently
\begin{gather*}
A = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left(\int_{0}^{a\cos t}\dfrac{ar}{\sqrt{a^2-r^2}}\, dr\right)\, dt = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left[-a\sqrt{a^2-r^2}\right]_{0}^{a\cos t}\, dt =\\[2ex] \int_{0}^{\pi/2}(a^2 -a^2\sin t)\, dt = a^2\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-1\right).
\end{gather*}
Thus (symmetry) the area outside the cylinders is $4\pi a^2-8A= 8a^2.$

**Remark**. We don't have to use polar coordinates.

\begin{gather*}
A=\int_{0}^{a}\left(\int_{0}^{\sqrt{ax-x^2}}\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2-y^2}}\, dy\right)\, dx =\int_{0}^{a}\left[a\arcsin\dfrac{y}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\right]_{0}^{\sqrt{ax-x^2}}\, dx =\\[2ex]
\int_{0}^{a}a\arcsin\sqrt{\dfrac{x}{x+a}}\, dx = a\int_{0}^{a}\arctan\sqrt{\dfrac{x}{a}}\, dx = [\text{Integration by parts}]\\[2ex]
\left[a(x+a)\arctan\sqrt{\dfrac{x}{a}}\right]_{0}^{a}-a\sqrt{a}\int_{0}^{a}
\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\, dx = a^2\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-1\right).
\end{gather*}